# ¿Cómo puedo sumar las tuplas de una lista de listas en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, lista

estoy intentando sumar una lista de listas, cuyos elementos son tuplas. (Podrían ser N listas) y que quede al final como resultado una lista de tuplas con la suma de los segundos elementos de la tupla, y que se mantenga el primer elemento igual.

La tupla es de la forma ( id_tupla, valor ), los elementos de la lista de listas (que son listas de tuplas) siempre van a tener el mismo tamaño, lo que quiero es mantener el id y sumar los valores de la primera lista con el valor de la segunda, o de la tercera y así sucesivamente (de la lista de listas).

Un ejemplo, sería el siguiente:

```
[[(205, 0.005376344086021506), (323, 0.010752688172043012), (325, 0.005376344086021506), (332, 0.005376344086021506), (334, 0.005376344086021506), (672, 0.005376344086021506), (678, 0.005376344086021506), (682, 0.005376344086021506), (687, 0.010752688172043012), (688, 0.016129032258064516), (726, 0.005376344086021506), (728, 0.005376344086021506), (745, 0.005376344086021506), (748, 0.005376344086021506), (756, 0.010752688172043012), (773, 0.010752688172043012), (801, 0.005376344086021506), (804, 0.005376344086021506), (806, 0.005376344086021506), (808, 0.005376344086021506), (819, 0.016129032258064516), (820, 0.005376344086021506), (838, 0.010752688172043012), (844, 0.005376344086021506), (866, 0.005376344086021506), (868, 0.005376344086021506), (869, 0.005376344086021506), (1023, 0.005376344086021506), (1024, 0.005376344086021506), (1141, 0.005376344086021506), (1290, 0.005376344086021506), (1315, 0.005376344086021506), (1319, 0.005376344086021506), (1445, 0.010752688172043012), (1485, 0.005376344086021506), (1566, 0.005376344086021506), (1567, 
0.005376344086021506), (1577, 0.005376344086021506), (1602, 0.005376344086021506), (1762, 0.005376344086021506), (1793, 0.010752688172043012), (1848, 0.005376344086021506), (1869, 0.005376344086021506), (1885, 0.005376344086021506), (1901, 0.005376344086021506)], [(205, 0.005305039787798408), (323, 0.002652519893899204), (325, 0.007957559681697613), (332, 0.002652519893899204), (334, 0.007957559681697613), (672, 0.002652519893899204), (678, 0.002652519893899204), (682, 0.005305039787798408), (687, 0.005305039787798408), (688, 0.002652519893899204), (726, 0.002652519893899204), (728, 0.002652519893899204), (745, 0.002652519893899204), (748, 0.002652519893899204), (756, 0.002652519893899204), (773, 0.002652519893899204), (801, 0.002652519893899204), (804, 0.005305039787798408), (806, 0.002652519893899204), (808, 0.03978779840848806), (819, 0.002652519893899204), (820, 0.002652519893899204), (838, 0.002652519893899204), (844, 0.002652519893899204), (866, 0.010610079575596816), (868, 0.010610079575596816), (869, 0.002652519893899204), (1023, 0.002652519893899204), (1024, 0.005305039787798408), (1141, 0.002652519893899204), (1290, 0.002652519893899204), (1315, 0.002652519893899204), (1319, 0.002652519893899204), (1445, 0.005305039787798408), (1485, 0.002652519893899204), (1566, 0.002652519893899204), (1567, 0.002652519893899204), (1577, 0.002652519893899204), (1602, 0.005305039787798408), (1762, 0.007957559681697613), (1793, 0.005305039787798408), (1848, 0.002652519893899204), (1869, 0.005305039787798408), (1885, 0.002652519893899204), (1901, 0.007957559681697613)]]
```

Es decir quedaría algo así:

```
[(205, X),.......(1901, Z)]
```

X será la suma de la primera tupla de la primera, segunda hasta la lista N.

Decir también que estoy haciéndolo en Python 3.9.5. Espero que me podáis ayudar :)

Comment: Parece que la pregunta se puede reducir a preguntar por la suma de tuplas (los últimos cuatro párrafos). Parece que toda la explicación previa no aporta.

Comment: Hola, es la primera pregunta que hago. Ahora que lo estoy viendo tienes razón ¿Debería de borrarlo? Un saludo

Comment: Si. Elimina todo lo que sobra y se entendera mejor. Lo otro es agregar el resultado que esperas (los 3 o 5 primeros elementos). Aclara si las listas son del mismo largo y contienen los mismos codigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución que funciona para una lista con N sublistas.

Cada sublista está compuesta de tuplas. El primer elemento es el id; el segundo es un valor.

Como todas las listas tienen los mismos id, puedo usar `zip` para agrupar los elementos de cada sublista. Siendo `lista` la variable que contiene la lista de sublistas, el "*" delante de `lista` en `zip(*lista)` desglosa la lista en sus elementos. Es equivalente a:

```
 lista = [sublista1, sublista2, sublista3, .... sublistaN]
 zip(sublista1, sublista2, ...)
```

Es decir, logramos el efecto de llamar a la función con N parámetros sin tener que escribirlo explícitamente.

La solución es:

```
total = []
for x in zip(*lista):
    cod = x[0][0]
    suma = sum(valor[1] for valor in x)
    total.append((cod, suma))
```

*versión one-liner*

```
total = [(x[0][0], sum(valor[1] for valor in x)) for x in zip(*lista)]
```

La variable `total` es una lista de tuplas, cada una con un id y la suma de los valores individuales de cada sublista.

Con el ciclo `for` vamos dejando en `x` una tupla de N elementos como estas:

```
((205, 0.005376344086021506), (205, 0.005305039787798408))
((323, 0.010752688172043012), (323, 0.002652519893899204))
((325, 0.005376344086021506), (325, 0.007957559681697613))
```

de cada tupla sumamos el segundo elemento (con indice 1) y teniendo el `id`, generamos una tupla con el resultado, que agregamos a `total`

**Demo**

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(total)
```

produce:

```
[(205, 0.010681383873819915),
 (323, 0.013405208065942215),
 (325, 0.013333903767719119),
 (332, 0.00802886397992071),
 (334, 0.013333903767719119),
 (672, 0.00802886397992071),
 (678, 0.00802886397992071),
 (682, 0.010681383873819915),
 (687, 0.01605772795984142),
 (688, 0.01878155215196372),
 (726, 0.00802886397992071),
 (728, 0.00802886397992071),
 (745, 0.00802886397992071),
 (748, 0.00802886397992071),
 (756, 0.013405208065942215),
 (773, 0.013405208065942215),
 (801, 0.00802886397992071),
 (804, 0.010681383873819915),
 (806, 0.00802886397992071),
 (808, 0.04516414249450957),
 (819, 0.01878155215196372),
 (820, 0.00802886397992071),
 (838, 0.013405208065942215),
 (844, 0.00802886397992071),
 (866, 0.015986423661618322),
 (868, 0.015986423661618322),
 (869, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1023, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1024, 0.010681383873819915),
 (1141, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1290, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1315, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1319, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1445, 0.01605772795984142),
 (1485, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1566, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1567, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1577, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1602, 0.010681383873819915),
 (1762, 0.013333903767719119),
 (1793, 0.01605772795984142),
 (1848, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1869, 0.010681383873819915),
 (1885, 0.00802886397992071),
 (1901, 0.013333903767719119)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! No tenía ni idea de que se podía de hacer de esta manera. Increíble conocimiento pythoniano!!!